# Poner la misma altura a todas las celdas que están dentro de un <tr>

Tags: html, html5

Trabajo en html5 tengo la siguiente tabla

Si las tablas se organizan en filas `<tr>` y Las celdas se encriben dentro de `<td>` si dentro de una fila hay muchos `<td>` si quiero que todos los `td` tengan la misma altura, tendría que darle la altura al `<tr>`?, **lo que quiero es que todas las celdas que están dentro de un `<tr>` tengan la misma altura, como lo puedo solucionar?**

```
<table border="1">


<caption>Ejemplo de tabla</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de CSS tuyo o Bootstrap para la creación de la tabla. Pero si directamente quieres TODOS los `<tr>` con la misma altura, sobreescribelos en tu CSS

Comment: @Excorpion el css lo tengo que hacer directamente en el html ya que el html lo voy a usar para crear un pdf

Comment: Que hay del ejemplo que te han dado ya ?

Comment: Funciona genial satisface a mi pregunta

Comment: A eso me refería jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta resolverlo con un height

```html
    <style>
        tr{
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    
    <table border="1">
    
    
        <caption>Ejemplo de tabla</caption>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <th>A</th>
              <th>B</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <td>A1</td>
              <td>B1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>2</th>
              <td>A2</td>
              <td>B2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </body>
```

Comment: Harry, como puedo hacer que las celdas que están contenidas en un tr tengan el mismo alto que ya le di, porque cuando le ingreso texto a las celdas varian su tama;o según el texto que va en ellas